# Port 5432 failed: FATAL: database "xxx" does not exist. in PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql

I am running a PostgreSQL 14 on my mac, tried to reinstall it since I forgot the password.

```
(base) % brew uninstall --force postgresql@14
(base) % brew cleanup -s              
(base) % brew install postgresql@14
```

I followed the commands above to uninstall it as well as its cache or files, and then install it again successfully.

I tried to set a new password but encounter an error

```
(base) % psql -h localhost
```

> psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "xxx" does not exist.

I guess this database xxx must be set up in the last installation, I thought `brew uninstall --force` would remove all the previous installation, but evidently it did not.

Now how would I solve this?

Comment: Try `psql postgres`.

Comment: Aren't there already hundreds of questions and answers about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If defaults don't work as they should, override them:

```sh
psql -h localhost -d postgres -U xxx -p 5432 -W
```

- `-d` specifies which db you want to connect to
- `-U` specifies which db user you want to connect as
- `-p` specifies the port
- `-W` specifies that you want to be prompted for password

---

This:

```sqh
psql -h localhost
```

should default to

```
psql -h localhost -d your_user_name
```

When you leave [`-d` parameter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-OPTION-DBNAME) unspecified, database defaults to a db named after the user you're running the command as:

> The default database user name is your operating-system user name. Once the database user name is determined, it is used as the default database name.

If it's somehow automatically trying to connect to DB `xxx` instead, you might still have [environment variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#R2-APP-PSQL-CONNECTING) in place[:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-ENVIRONMENT-PGDATABASE)

> When the defaults aren't quite right, you can save yourself some typing by setting the environment variables [**`PGDATABASE`**, `PGHOST`, `PGPORT` and/or `PGUSER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) to appropriate values.

Or a [`.pgpass`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html) config file in your user directory:

```
localhost:5432:xxx:username:password
```

Or, you're just on user named `xxx`. These would result `-d xxx`. Note that it first tries to authenticate, and only then it'll tell you whether the database exists, which would mean that your user `xxx` does exist on that instance/cluster, that you did authenticate correctly, but after that it tried to welcome you into a db `xxx`, which does not exist.

---

If you forgot the password to your local Postgres DB, you don't need to reinstall - you can set local connection for a given db/user as trusted in [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html), connect, set your password, then lock `pg_hba.conf` back down. It's also possible to switch to system user postgres and try to use socket based auth, which should be allowed by default.